# SharePoint Online API. Why does it only return date of query?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, office365apis

I am trying to return data using the SharePoint Online API, and this query returns the correct number of items, but only returns the time of my query.

```
https://MYSITE.sharepoint.com/MYSubsite/_api/lists/getbytitle('MYTasksList')/items?select=Title
```

I got the query code here: [Get to know the SharePoint 2013 REST service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/fp142380.aspx)

Comment: You miss the $ before the select:

https://MYSITE.sharepoint.com/MYSubsite/_api/lists/getbytitle('MYTasksList')/items?$select=Title

Answer (score 2):

As @Marko said, you need to replace `select` with `$select`. Here is a nice resource about [OData Query Operations in SharePoint REST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385.aspx), that you can refer to for further details.

The url will look something like 
`https://MYSITE.sharepoint.com/MYSubsite/_api/lists/getbytitle('MYTasksList')/items?$select=Title`